Como leer una tabla temporal desde Genexus
Tengo un SP creado en SQL Server, que al final devuele registros en una #tabla_temporal.
Cómo puedo leer (desde un For Each normal) esta tabla temporal desde Genexus 18, que contiene los datos devueltos por el SP después de haberlo ejecutado.
He leído que, asociando la tabla temporal a un DataView, pero no he podido implementarlo.
Nota:
1.- No requiero nuevas tablas (no temporales), sí o sí requiero leer la #tabla devuelta por el SP.
2.- La ejecución del SP la hago a través del comando SQL [!'Execute StoreProcedure Parametro1, Parametro2...'!], por lo que no requiero crear ningún objeto tipo StoreProcedure (en Genexus).
3.-No requiero modificar el SP
